# SQL Server - Overlapped text in option windows

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-data-tools

I'm having problem with my SQL Server tools (2017) on my new laptop - in some option windows the text is overlapped or some options are not visible. E.g. -  attached.

Changing resolution or scale and layout doesn't do the job. I've looked through the options but nothing has worked so far, nor can I find any similar problem online. Any ideas?

I'm running Windows 10 Pro, Dell Latitude 5490, Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620.

[SSMS Cube processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kzu4.png)
[SSDT Dimention Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl7wn.png)

Answer (score 1):

Following might help

try setting the DPI scaling in the properties window:

[image]

Comment: Worked for the attached tab in the previous post but there is still the same problem with others. Some options are hidden in the bottom of the window and there is no scrolling available.